# How to find file with string

Tags: grep

I currently using grep til find files which has some relations to ax.

The way i am currently searching is by

`grep -ril "ax" .`

But this also finds files with ax as a substring like words such as 
max, axis and so on.

How do i ensure the the word I am looking for only have `ax` in it .. and isn't a substring of some sort?

Comment: You will need to define **exactly** how the word should *"have ax in it"* yet **not** have *"ax as a substring"*

Comment: Can you please put an example of what input you have and the output you're expecting?

Answer (score 3):

You can use -w option in grep to find the same.

```
 grep -w 'ax' *
```

output

```
l.txt:ax
```

above command will search exactly for the word "ax" in path then it prints the filename and string searched for.

If you need line number with filename you can use below command

```
 grep -win 'ax' *

l.txt:1:ax
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, simply adding spaces before and after "ax" ought to do the trick.

```
grep -irl " ax " *
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: well.. Not quite... I could also be Axconfig